# the type java.util.optional cannot be resolved. it is indirectly referenced from required - stack overflow

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

```
The type java.util.Optional cannot be resolved. it is indirectly referenced from required is the compilation issue.
```

I have developed an application in java 8. But on my jumphost server, java 7 is the latest. I can not upgrade the jumphost to 8, so had to downgrade my project to be compiled in java7.  Now my interface is throwing this compile time issue.

It is a basic spring-boot + maven +mongodb project. I am using MongoRepository to connect to the db. 
    Interface which throws the issue is :

```
public interface AlertsFiredMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<AlertsFired, ObjectId>
```

And my config class application.java for spring-boot code has mongoClient . I don't have any other configuration for mongo db.

```
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient()
    {
        //connecting to just primary db is also fine.

        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongoURI"));

    }
```

It should be compiled and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE is the latest version that works with Java 7.

Every later version require min Java 8.

Comment: I updated it to 1.5.9 version and I am able to compile the application now. Thank you